# Градусы: найти угол между первым и последним значением

Tags: python, list, numpy

Имеем [список](https://dropmefiles.com/9SlO0)  `a = [131.47, 131.475, 131.4829, 131.4733, 131.42, 131.48, 131.495, 131.5165, 131.5448]`

По сути есть сами эти значения и длинна оси на которой они находятся. Значит x и y. Допустим я беру первое значение списка `a` и последнее. Как высчитать угол в градусах от первого значения до последнего?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120975/discussion-on-question-by-nikolay-smirnov-------).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

если взять ваш [датасет с 1000 значениями](https://dropmefiles.com/9SlO0) в качестве координат по оси `Y` и в качестве координат по оси `X` считать значения: `[0, 1, 2, ..., 999]`, то угол между осью `X` и прямой, образованной точками `A(0, <первое значение из списка "a">)` и `B(999, <последнее значение из списка "a">)`, можно посчитать так:

```
angle_deg = np.rad2deg(np.arctan( (a[-1] - a[0]) / (len(a) - 1 ) ))

In [187]: angle_deg
Out[187]: 0.17726649677395562
```

PS значение угла в градусах.

---

Подозреваю ваши ожидания получить угол "в районе 30-40 градусов", основаны на визуализации данных:

```
In [190]: ax = pd.Series(a).plot()

In [191]: plt.plot([0, 999], [a[0], a[-1]], c="r")
Out[191]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7ff558934250>]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если немного растянуть **те же самые значения** по оси `X` то угол будет "слегка" другим:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
или сжать:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

если хотите увидеть более правдоподобный угол, можно задать одинаковые пределы по осям `X` и `Y`:

```
In [196]: plt.xlim(0, 1000)
Out[196]: (0.0, 1000.0)

In [197]: plt.ylim(0, 1000)
Out[197]: (0.0, 1000.0)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, кстати, логично - там практически все значения лежат на прямой, параллельной оси `X`, угол близок к `0`.

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, я написал в ответе - результат - это угол в __градусах__

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, "прямая меньшей размерности" - вы о прямой в одномерном пространстве? ;)

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, тогда ваша задача существенно упрощается! В одномерном пространстве существует __одна единственная прямая__, на которой лежат все точки принадлежащие данному пространству. :-D Очень надеюсь, что вы не будете нас спрашивать как найти угол в одномерном пространстве...

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, это __величина угла в градусах__. Причем здесь синус?

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNU8X.png - красная линия - это и есть ваш угол

Comment: а вы мой ответ весь прочитали? ;)

Comment: @Nikolay_Smirnov, в общем, все что я хотел и мог сказать на тему угла - я уже написал в ответе и комментариях )